# In notepad++, replace the defined line break with a symbol

Tags: notepad++

For example, I have a text like this:

```
驕傲淫亂嫉妒
0108
我看到你的靈魂和面容起了變化
0109
因為你心中的那只巨獸正
張牙舞爪的爬出來
0110
你看到人心潛藏的罪惡
0111
卻看不到我心中的痛苦
0112
```

I would like to join 2 continous lines(there's no number being between) with a "|", then replace the numbers with blanks.
For the example above, the result is:

```
驕傲淫亂嫉妒

我看到你的靈魂和面容起了變化

因為你心中的那只巨獸正|張牙舞爪的爬出來

你看到人心潛藏的罪惡

卻看不到我心中的痛苦
```

I do not have much knowledge about notepad++. Could anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Notepad++ is just a text editor. Start typing?

Comment: I just confused, it's notepad++ right? what doubt in that, you just type..

Comment: But the real text file has about 7000 lines like the example. I could not retype it. Regards.

Comment: I can replace the numbers with blanks by wildcard replace in Word. But I don't know how to join lines. I think notepad++ is more functional, but I can't find many guides of replacing in notepad++. Regards.

Comment: I could have given it a try if it wasn't in chineese

Comment: Go ahead, show me the way, I'll try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your problem correctly then a simple regular expression in Find & Replace will solve your problem correctly.

Your Find string `[0-9]+` and your Replace string should be `empty`

After above replace, search the expression `(.+)\r\n(.+)` and replace it with `\1|\2`. This will help you join the continuous lines.

Comment: Thank phoenix, but I still need to join 2 continous lines with a "|". I can't find the right expression to define 2 continous lines.

Comment: @VũTiếnPhát: edited my answer to include solution of joining continuous lines.

Comment: Thank you very much Phoenix, I'll vote for your asnswer as soon as I could.